# JEE6 Interceptors - extract method variable

Tags: java, java-ee-6, cdi, interceptor, jboss-weld

Is it possible to extract the value of a method variable once/while it is intercepted? I don;t wish to intercept the parameters but an attribute value within the method? e.g.

```
Business Logic: 

@MyInterceptor
void myMethod(Object o){

 ArrayList myList= null;
 myList= dao.getRecords(o.getId) //intercept the result of this dao call


//I only want to call doWork after I have 'validated' contents of myList in interceptor

 doWork(myList)


}


The Interceptor:  

@Interceptor
@MyInterceptor
MyInterceptor{

@AroundInvoke{
public Object invoke(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {

 //retrieve the contents of myList above and perform validation
 //if it passes validation call ctx.proceed else return error

}

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid you can't really do this with interceptors because they have no access to method internal variables (just look at InvocationContext [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/interceptor/InvocationContext.html)). So your only chance to do this would to make `myList` a beans property and then do this in your interceptor.

```
@AroundInvoke{
public Object invoke(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
    if(ctx.getTarget() instanceof BeanWithListProperty) {
        Object toProceed = ctx.proceed(); 
        BeanWithListProperty bean = (BeanWithListProperty) ctx.getTarget();
        List list = bean.getMyList();
        return toProceed;
    }
    return ctx.proceed();
}
```

Other option would be to use [Decorators](http://sysout.be/2011/06/22/java-ee6-decorators-decorating-classes-at-injecting-time/) which will lead to slightly more readable and efficient code.

However I don't like these solutions much, seems to me that your code is really not well designed, what are you trying to achive?

Comment: Thanks, another option I considered was moving the DAO to the interceptor but it has other drawbacks and is not really suitable to all use cases..thanks for the reply